# asp.net core appsettings.json include reference to anthor file

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

I am working on a C# ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, angular is the front end. I have a requirement to put some text (multiline) inside a text file and point to it in `appsettings.json` as below:

```
"MySettings": {
    "Parameters": {
       "instructionFile": "filename.txt",
     },
 }
```

I can read these in, but I don't know how to access the '`filename.txt`', so as to '`System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename.txt)`', where should I put that `filename.txt` and what's the full path to it? my `Startup` has `app.UseStaticFiles()`, so I assume I should put it inside `wwwroot/?` but when I put it there, I tried `~/filename.txt`, it didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the appsettings.json file using IConfiguration like

```
private IConfiguration _configuration;

string fileName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("MySettings:Parameters:instructionFile")
```

In order to read the content of the file:

```
// Load the souce file if the file location is within the project, if it's a url then get it via making http requrest
string _filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @""+ fileName +"");
string fileContent= File.ReadAllText(_filePath);
```

Thanks

Comment: this doesn't look like it will be able to get the content of the instructionFile, does it?